# Clean up GNU parallel sem

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I've run some commands using `sem -j <number> <command>`. Then I cancelled the whole script.

Now, even after rebooting the machine, I cannot use `sem` any more, even `sem -j 2 "echo HELLO"` waits eternally.

How can I clean up the semaphores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored in `~/.parallel/semaphores`, but they should really clean themselves over time.

Are you running a very old version?

Comment: `sem --version` brings `GNU parallel 20181223`. Can I delete the directories in `semaphores`?

Comment: You can. It is perfectly safe.